# Speeding up "row_number" queries in postgres

Tags: postgresql

This relates to my earlier question here: [Atomic updates to ordering in a table for a waiting list application](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303368/atomic-updates-to-ordering-in-a-table-for-a-waiting-list-application)

Given a table that looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE leaderboard (
  id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  email CITEXT NOT NULL,               
  score BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_leaderboard_email_unique ON leaderboard (email);
CREATE INDEX ix_leaderboard_ordering ON leaderboard (score DESC, created_at ASC, email);
```

I would like to get the position of a specific user in the table. I am currently using a query like this:

```sql
SELECT email, position, score
  FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() over(
      ORDER BY score DESC, created_at ASC
    ) AS position
      FROM leaderboard
  ) result
 WHERE email='email@domain.tld';
```

With an analyze that looks like this (the table has 2 million rows in it):

```sql
                                                                                QUERY PLAN                                                                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on result  (cost=0.55..190060.55 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=3.500..2726.278 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: (result.email = 'email@domain.tld'::citext)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1999999
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.55..165060.55 rows=2000000 width=90) (actual time=3.493..836.064 rows=2000000 loops=1)
         ->  Index Only Scan using ix_leaderboard_ordering on leaderboard  (cost=0.55..130060.55 rows=2000000 width=74) (actual time=0.043..187.361 rows=2000000 loops=1)
               Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.086 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 5
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.636 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.200 ms, Emission 3.070 ms, Total 3.906 ms
 Execution Time: 2726.982 ms
(12 rows)
```

Just wondering if there are ways to speed this up outside using a materialized view (I tried the materialized view, and it does work, but takes time to refresh).

If this is all the speed I can get out of it, that is fine, we will use the view, but if we can put that off until we absolutely need it, it would be better.

For reference, we are using Postgres 13.2

Comment: Personally I would use a relative position indicator of type `numeric`, so when you insert or relocate an entry between P (previous) and N (next) its position becomes `(P+N)/2`. For instance if you insert between `2` and `3`, the new position is `2.5`. No other entry needs to be updated or shifted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a LIMIT 1 should always give you the right answer (since there is a unique index on email) and allows it to stop once that answer is found.  That will make it 50% faster "on average" but more than that if your queries are often for emails towards the top.  (On the other hand, no benefit if you query for ones that are not even present--but you could preselect to rule that out if needed.)

Also, this being citext makes things about 33% slower for me.  Maybe you can convert the emails to lower case and then just store as text?

Comment: Ah, awesome! This schema is actually a test, in practice the email column will be replaced by a `user_id` foreign key, so that should help out. Thank you!